# How can a user profile picture be hosted on Facebook or other external site?

Tags: discussion

I have Request Policy on Firefox, which blocks external files from a website unless it has been whitelisted. Randomly today, I noticed it was blocking a [user's](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/36991/mostafa-lafta) profile image. Apparently, this person has their image hosted on Facebook.

How exactly does someone link to an external site for their photo? When I go to change my image, I only get the option to upload a photo (which itself is a relatively new feature) or use Gravatar.

Is it Gravatar that is linking to the image externally? I haven't used the Gravatar image ever since uploading my own, so I don't remember how it sotred/linked images.

Or is the "upload photo from web" option actually just linking instead of copying to the StackExchange network?

Comment: Stackexchange login with Facebook as auth provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that this are users which login to Stackexchange with Facebook credentials. Their Facebook profile picture is most likely used as Stackexchange profile picture.